# C language. Length of the string without using null-termination

Tags: c, string, pascal, string-length

strlen() considers that '\00' is end of the string. How to calculate real length? E.g. there is [AnsiString type in Pascal](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refsu12.html#x35-380003.2.6). It can contain many #$00 , but Length(s) will give correct result. Debugging of compiled pascal code shows that pascal puts length to dword before first element (@s[0] - 4) and recalculate it for me if needed. Is there something the same in C language (or I must manually to allocate memory and take care of -1 - element)? If no, C language is much worse than Pascal.

Comment: If you know that all of your strings are stored in memory created by `malloc`, and you don’t care about portability at all, you can back up a few bytes before the start of the malloced block and parse whatever data is there. I don’t know its format, but it’s how `free` knows how much memory to free. It seems like a bad idea though.

Comment: By C definition, a string is C **always** ends and includes a `'\0'`.  Otherwise it is not a string.

Answer (score 2):

The C standard says that strings end with a NUL character. The string may be stored in an array that is larger than that, but there is no way to get the size of an array if you are only given a pointer to the array.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f(char *s)
{
    printf("%s\n", s);
    // you can't get the size of array s here
}

int main(void)
{
    char s[100] = "hi";
    printf("size of s = %zu\n", sizeof(s)); // this works
    f(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Question

> Is there something the same in C language?

No, there is nothing like that in C or the standard C library. However, the language provides the building blocks to define such a type and create API functions to work on the type.

Something like:

```
typedef struct AnsiString
{
    size_t len;
    char* data;
} AnsiString;

AnsiString createAnsiString(size_t len)
{
   AnsiString s;
   s.len = len;
   s.data = malloc(len);
   return s;
}

void deleteAnsiString(AnsiString s)
{
   free(s.data);
}
```

Then you can use

```
AnsiString s = createAnsiString(10);

// Use s as you please

deleteAnsiString(s);
```

Comment: But what about recalculating len when data changed? It's very big code. I can't believe that Pascal do it by itself and in C i must to do it myself.

Comment: @user4753163 Rule of thumb: C makes you do _everything_ by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest problem with this question is that a string isn't considered a 'type' in C. It's a pattern of values... Think about integers that are multiples of ten, for example. They all end in 0, yet you can store them in any type of integer providing they're in range. Strings are similar; you can store them in arrays of `char`, `signed char`, `wchar_t`, etc. They're not types, though... They're values that fit a specific pattern.

That pattern is similar to the "multiples of ten" I described above: A string is a sequence of digits that ends at the first `'\0'`. If there is no NUL character, it's not a string. It's just a sequence of characters.

If you want the size of the array, and the array hasn't yet been converted to a pointer type, you can use `sizeof array` because the array still carries the size information. However, once the array is converted to a pointer (when calling a function with the array identifier as an argument, as a common example) you need to manually carry the size information. Standard functions commonly use separate size arguments as a result, for example `fgets(array, sizeof array, stdin);`.

Whether you consider C to be better or worse than Pascal is a matter of opinion, and you have one good point. The main point of Pascal vs. C is ease of developing a compiler, which you'll discover if you ever try to write one (a great way of learning everything about the language, btw).

However, in the grand scheme of things this is only a small part of a larger issue, which Pascal also mostly suffers from. If you're going into the business of comparing programming languages based on ability to write expressive code, you might find [this article ranking programming languages on expressive power](http://redmonk.com/dberkholz/2013/03/25/programming-languages-ranked-by-expressiveness/) to be useful.

Best of luck with your language studies :) It's nice to see people developing code that uses the maximum expressive potential of a language.

Comment: (such studies are complicated because Pascal dialects range from something K&R level to something closer to C++ than to C)